# Как определить был ли заблокирован экран в android приложении?

Tags: java, android

Использую Android Studio, нужно делать определённые действия в приложении при блокировки экрана. Находил решения тут же на stackoverflow, но они старые. Те методы которые использовались ранее, сейчас android studio перечеркивает.

В общем, условно нужно свести код к проверке: если экран потушили кнопкой питания(т.е. заблокирован), то делать что-то там.

Comment: Экран потушен и заблокирован - это две разные вещи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот есть способ:

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //it is locked
} else {
 //it is not locked
}
```

Так вот подобные вопросы [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317331/detecting-when-screen-is-locked), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170563/android-detect-phone-lock-event) и [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002032/how-to-find-the-screen-is-locked-in-android).

### UPDATE

Если метод устарел, то из документации можно взять [другой](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager#isDeviceLocked()):

> Returns whether the device is currently locked and requires a PIN,
> pattern or password to unlock.

Comment: Да, именно об этом способе я и говорил что android studio перечеркивает метод inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode как устаревший

Comment: @JS1love, обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Надо воспользоваться бродкастом, который рассылается системой при выключении экрана, примерно так:

```
public class ScreenStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public ScreenStateBroadcastReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //checking has screen been switched off?
        if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
             //blah-blah
             //что-то делаем здесь
        }
    }
}
```

Не забудьте продекларировать ресивер с манифесте ну или можно в коде его тоже зарегистрировать.

[Документация здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

Answer (score 0):

Мне лично помогло вот такое решение, которое использовал в onPause методе.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();

if(!isScreenOn){
     //...
}
```